# How to catch onload event on css styles?

Tags: javascript

I load css

```
var ss = document.createElement("link");
var url = 'http://site.ru/style.css';
ss.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
ss.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
ss.setAttribute("href", url);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ss);
```

I want to call function after css loading, but tag link hasn't onload event, is there a way to do it?

Comment: is your javascript running on the same domain ?

Comment: yes it is. the problem is that i cant do something like ss.onload=myfunc();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently don't load that css stuff via Ajax, but you *could* do it. That way, you also have your *callback* when data transfer has finished.  I'm using jQuery in this example to make things short and convinient.

**Be aware**: This only works if your javascript & your css files are located on the same domain.

```
$.get('http://site.ru/style.css', function( css ) {
    $('<style>', {
        html: css
    }).appendTo( document.head || document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0] );
});
```

Simplified vanilla Javascript might look like:

```
var req;

try {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch ( e ) {
    req = new ActiveXObject( 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP' ); // there are plenty more
} finally {
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( req.readyState === 4 ) {  // simplified/shortened
            var head          = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement,
                lnk           = document.createElement('style');
                lnk.type      = 'text/css';
                lnk.textContent = lnk.text = req.responseText;

            head.insertBefore(lnk, head.firstChild);
        }
    };

    req.open('GET', 'http://site.ru/style.css', true);
    req.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but I suggest using a framework like jQuery or Prototype here. jQuery offers a simple "ready"-event that can be attached to css files. And the whole AJAX-processing is more straightforward.

Comment: @acme: what do you mean ? The `DOMContentLoaded` event which `.ready()` internally listens for if available will fire when the DOM is ready. stylesheets and images may not be loaded already at this point, plus I guess the OP wants to insert a stylesheet dynamically beyond pageload.

Comment: ...and I'm *really* interested in why someone would anonymously downvote that answer. oh gosh ;)

Comment: Any idea how you could do this but keep the relative file locations for loading images etc from the stylesheet?